# Have different devices have the same IP when connecting to a router that is connected to a router

Tags: networking, router, ip

Here is what I want to achieve: I need different devices to reliably always have the same IP address. These devices would be connected after one another.

In order to achieve that, I thought I'd just use a seperate router from my everyday one. I'd only ever connect one device to that seperate router, and I'd set it to have a DHCP IP range of only one (192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.2). This way, any device that connects will get that specific IP-address assigned.

This works great, but only if I don't connect that seperate router to my everyday one. Once I do that, It seems like my everyday one assigns the IP address. However, I need to connect them, because else I cant access the device via that everyday router, which I need to do.

So, how can I get make above work?

Edit:
My everyday router is a linksys N300 E9000 with standard settings. It has DHCP toggled on, so it will distribute IPs dynamically to everything connected.
The seperate router is an older one, a netgear WGR614, also default settings except the extremely limited dhcp range. It also has DHCP toggled on.

Comment: Any reason you dont just configure your two devices with a static IP?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you want to do this?  What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @kicken You misunderstand, I have many different devices (possibly thousands), that need to have the same ip-address assigned to them when I connect one of them to the router. My routers have static ips, of course.

Comment: @RonTrunk The devices I need to connect all have a webpage that is accessible via their assigned ip-address. I need to test if the webpage works, and for the sake of automation do I not want to have to spend minutes looking the actual IP-address up

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your main router from taking over DHCP assignments you need to create isolated networks.  This means when you connect your secondary router you need to connect it's WAN port to one of your main router's LAN ports.  Your secondary router/gateway must also be in normal router mode and not something like AP/bridge mode.

In order to access your device then from devices on the main router, you'll need to configure a port forwarding rule on the secondary router to point to the device IP:Port you need to connect to.  Finally when connecting you will connect to the secondary router's IP:Port combination.

**Alternative setup**

Assuming you're trying to access these devices from a desktop PC, an alternative option is to just connect your PC to the secondary router rather than connect your secondary router to your primary router.  If you need your PC connected to the primary router at the same time, then you'll need a second ethernet port on your PC ([easy to add](https://www.newegg.com/Network-Interface-Cards/SubCategory/ID-27) if not already present).

Once your PC is connected to the secondary router you configure your PC with a static IP on that interface so it's not trying to grab the one from your one-ip DHCP pool.

**Alternative alternative solution**

With the second ethernet port, you could skip the second router entirely and just connect your devices directly to your PC.  Find some DHCP server software and set it up on the PC to serve an address on your secondary port.  Then connect your device directly to your PC using that port.